# Angular Universal - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Trying to move my application to SSR with angular Universal. But can not do api calls from server (breakpoint in backend is never hit)

```
export class PostService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { 
    this.myAppUrl = environment.appUrl;
      this.myApiUrl = 'post/';
  }

public getPosts(page: number, pageSize: number): Observable<GetPostsResponse> {
    
    var url = this.myAppUrl + this.myApiUrl + "all" + "?page="+page+"&pageSize="+ pageSize;
    console.log("GetPosts:" + url);
    return this.http.get<GetPostsResponse>(url)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    );
  }
```

posts.effect.ts

```
  loadPosts$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PostActions.loadPosts),
      withLatestFrom(this.store),
      mergeMap(([action, state]) => {
        console.log("Inside effect loadPosts: ");
        return this.store.select(getUser).pipe(take(1)).pipe(mergeMap(user => {
     
          return this.postService.getPosts(state.post.currentPage + 1, pageSize).pipe(
            map(posts => {
              console.log("After getPosts");
              return PostActions.loadPostsSuccess({ pageSize: pageSize, posts });
            }
            ),
            catchError(error => {
              console.log("Error getPosts");
              this.toastr.error('Error', 'Loading posts');
              return of(PostActions.loadPostsFailure({ error }));
            })
          )
        }));
      }
      )
    );
  });
```

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        if(isPlatformServer(this.platformId)){
          this.store.dispatch(PostActions.loadPosts());
          this.posts$ =  this.store.select(getPosts);
        }
        if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
          //TODO: read from statekey?!
        }
    }
```

Console log:

Inside effect loadPosts:

GetPosts:http://localhost:5001/post/all?page=1&pageSize=15

Errormessage: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

I have tried adding HttpClientModule to app.server.module.ts but still same problem

Comment: this is seems like fine, I think you're getting error from where you want to call getPosts() function, can you please share how & where you used getPosts() ?

Comment: @SefatAnam added more of the code

Comment: Yeah, on my live environment my application completely hangs when doing ajax calls back to the api during SSR. In .NET we have something like [`SupplyData`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/merge/release/2.1-to-release/3.1/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingOptions.cs#L42) to do this. To be used [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Services/SpaPrerenderingService.cs#L143). But for NodeJS I can't help you any further...